# Innosetup deletes abc.msi when it's still needed

Tags: inno-setup

During my Inno Setup installation, a file abc.msi is copied in the installation directory and then correctly installed.
But during uninstallation the abc.msi is not uninstalled.
After an investigation in the logs of uninstallation, i understood the reason. The following is part of the log, where i replaced date/hour with a number to be more clear:

```
0. [deleting all the files... INCLUDING abc.msi!]
1. Uninstallation process succeeded.
2. Removed all? Yes
3. Need to restart Windows? No
4. INFO: Execute command: msiexec.exe /x "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallationDir\abc\abc.msi" /QUIET /NORESTART
5. ERROR: Command failed. Error code: 1619
```

The error is due to the fact that the command on step 4 is called too late (after the deletion of abc.msi, see step 0) so we have error on 5.

Now, the the uninstall command is placed as following:

```
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(...)
[code...]
begin
  if (CurUninstallStep = usUninstall) then
  begin
    [code...]
    ExecCommand('msiexec.exe', ' /x "' + pathTo_abc.msi + '" /QUIET /NORESTART');
    [code...]
  end
end
```

so my question is where to call the command to be executed before the deletion of abc.msi instead of CurUninstallStepChanged, or what's the correct installStep to use instead of usUninstall. I also tried usPostUninstall, with no differences.

Comment: That sounds weird. Look at the [`code that runs`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Projects/Uninstall.pas#L643). First is fired the `CurUninstallStepChanged` event method with `usUninstall` step and after that is processed uninstallation and logged step 2 in your log example. In short, `CurUninstallStepChanged` event with `usUninstall` step is fired before anything is uninstalled (deleted). And it should work that way.

Comment: Do you mean that i did it right?

Comment: Yes. What's in that `usUninstall` step block should execute before anything is uninstalled. One thing comes to my mind, are you running that command synchronously, are you waiting for it to finish ?

Comment: I think it's not synchronously (it wasn't written by me, i am just changing something in it).
Anyway i just noticed that i could put the command in function InitializeUninstallProgressForm(), that will be called for sure before the deletion of the files.

Comment: The `InitializeUninstallProgressForm` is called right before the `CurUninstallStepChanged` with `usUninstall`, so that's not a solution. You must ensure to run that command synchronously.

Comment: What about adding `DelTree(ExpandConstant('{app}\ABC.msi'), False, True, False);` function in `usDone` of `CurUninstallStepChanged`? But probably there is no `ewWaitUntilTerminated` for the MSI Exec function which causes the issue, as the Uninstaller is probably faster than MSI process.

Comment: Thanks TLama and RobeN for your anwsers. Now i am following another way without using abc.msi at all during uninstall.

The uninstall can be done using the registry value:

`msiexec.exe /x {12345678-9ABC-DEF0-1234-56789ABCDEF0} /NORESTART`

But still I have to test it, i will let you know.

Comment: For some reason, the command listed in the previous comment didn't work (but it works from command line!). Error: `Internal error: Unknown constant "12345678-9ABC-DEF0-1234-56789ABCDEF0"`.

So I moved the uninstall in another part of the code, where it's executed when msi is still not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

use this sintax -> {{guid} the double { is a escape character so it tells inno setup this is literal value and not constant like {sys}. Sorry for my english.

You should use the product code and not the msi file. Why? product code is always available and it is unique. The file can be deleted or changed and your uninstall will fail.

I created a solution that I called universal uninstaller. It search a specific string in the display name string value of the registry HKLM or HKLM32 and when it finds it, it reads the uninstall string. If it contains msiexec, it ignores it and uses the key name witch is the same as the product quote with the suffix /qn. If it's not a msi, it uses the uninstall string. If I know the uninstaller I add the necessary parameters to be silent when I call the function. Why I do this? I use inno setup as a bootstrap for installing and configuring other installers. When I receive new versions I don't have to change inno setup script and compile again. I just overwrite the old installer, using the same name.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Do I need the double { also when i close the string or only when i open?
(Thanks and don't worry for the english, i am not so good in that too.)